# How to scale my app to new retina 4.5 1136x640 resolution?

Tags: ios, retina-display

How do I scale my app to new retina 4.5 resolution (1136x640)?

I have existing xibs and storyboard (non-xib) based applications, and can't find any information about how to auto-scale to new resolution.

Please, give me any links on developer.apple.com or themes on stackoverflow or any other help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to support iOS6 and higher only? In case you wish to keep your project iOS4 or iOS5 compatible, simply add the new Default-Image and make sure the autoResizingMask/s (UIViewAutoresizing) of your views are properly set up to scale. There is no need to use Auto-Layout!

Comment: If you have Xcode 4.5, on the bottom right hand corner of your storyboard (right next to the zoom out button) there should be an icon which shows the 4 inch screen in which you can adjust your existing UI. Unless your using something like auto-layout, your app will not automatically scale to the new resolution.

Comment: @Till Thanks! I just add Default-568h@2x.png and my app works in 1136x640 resolution! Some frames need to be coorected for new height, for fix it i use autoResizingMask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has given the Auto Layout mechanism to allow current and future versions of apps to scale to any size (for both iOS and OSX). I would recommend you check out the [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) as your first port of call.

Apple has also shared a few developer talk videos from WWDC 2012 which explain the Auto layout mechanism in a tutorial screencast manner (valid developer account needed)

- [WWDC 2012: Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)
- [WWDC 2012: Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232)
- [WWDC 2012: Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228)

Comment: But Auto Layout doesn't work with ios 5, right? Your apps now have support ios5? or only 5.1? And what can i do with my non-xib applications where interface maked programmatically? Calculate height of screen and set it? Thanks!

Comment: @MihaelIsaev correct, ignore this answer if you plan to keep your project iOS4 or 5 compatible.

Comment: Yes I did forget that Auto Layout only seems to work on iOS6. @Till answer would be more valid if you want to keep backward compatibility